# How do I access specific schemas in hibernate spring?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring, schema

I use Hibernate-Spring and I am trying to access a specific schema in a db but don't know how. The name of the table is not doing the trick. I was hoping that annotation would help be but it hasn't so far. Note: I am not trying to create a schema, I just want to access it. I use Spring 2.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set schema in your mappings:

```
@Table(name="myentity", schema="some")

<class name="MyEntity" table="myentity" schema="some">
```

or use default:

```
hibernate.default_schema="some"
```

Comment: I tried the annotation but got this error: "- The attribute schema is undefined for the annotation 
  type Table"

Comment: So you are using org.hibernate.annotations.Table instead of java.persistence.Table, then just set default_schema.